# Why two formLogin configured in Spring Authorization Server Sample code

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I'm checking latest [Spring Authorization Server v0.2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server) and found two `formLogin()` configured on the provided [sample authorizationserver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/boot/oauth2-integration).

One is [AuthorizationServerConfig.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/samples/boot/oauth2-integration/authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java):

```java
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }
```

Another one is [DefaultSecurityConfig.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/samples/boot/oauth2-integration/authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/DefaultSecurityConfig.java):

```java
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

My question is:

- why there are two `formLogin()`s configured
- If I wanted to customize `formLogin()` which one should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the `formLogin()` configuration in `AuthorizationServerConfig` is purely a *"convenience configuration"*, as it will setup the `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` and perform the redirect to `/login` when the current request is not authenticated.

For example, when the client is redirected to `/oauth2/authorize` and the user is not authenticated, the user will be redirected to `/login`, which will match on the `SecurityFilterChain` defined by `DefaultSecurityConfig` NOT `AuthorizationServerConfig`.

Basically, the `formLogin()` in `AuthorizationServerConfig` serves the sole purpose of performing the redirect to `/login`, which is ultimately matched on the `DefaultSecurityConfig` `SecurityFilterChain`.

Comment: thanks... so if I wanted to add `remember-me` feature then I'd use `DefaultSecurityConfig.java` right?

Comment: Yes, use `DefaultSecurityConfig` for all other security configuration - `AuthorizationServerConfig` is used for OAuth security configuration only.